# How to reconcile Genesis 22:2 and Jeremiah 7:31 on human sacrifice?

Tags: john

> Genesis 22:2 Then God said, "Take your son, your only son, whom you love--Isaac--and go to the region of Moriah. Sacrifice him there as a burnt offering on a mountain I will show you."

> Jeremiah 7:31 31 They have built the high places of Topheth in the Valley of Ben Hinnom to burn their sons and daughters in the fire—something I did not command, nor did it enter my mind.

Was the thought of human sacrifice ever in God's mind?

And then there is the special case:

> Romans 8:32 He who did not spare his own Son but gave him up for us all

Comment: The ram was already caught in the thicket as father and son ascended the mountain.God had already provided.(+1 Good question.

Comment: Human sacrifice was quite common among the various ancient Middle-Eastern nations and religions. Abraham's story marks Judaism's historical departure from such pagan practices.

Answer (score 3):

The thought of humans sacrificing humans had never entered the mind of God.

From everlasting, his intention was redemption, through his own Son, manifested in humanity.

Jesus Christ is the lamb slain :

> from the foundation of the world [Revelation 13:8 KJV]

God's intention (before the world began) was that humanity should have eternal life :

> In hope of eternal life, which God, that cannot lie, promised before the world began;
> [Titus 1:2 KJV]

God desired to set forth a scenario, and to demonstrate his intentions. For this reason he tried Abraham and drew Abraham into the scenario.

But the lamb was already caught in the thicket as father and son ascended the mountain.

There never was a possibility that God would let Abraham kill and sacrifice Isaac.

But his own Son, he did not spare, as the OP states.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus was the lamb slain "before the foundation of the world".
Yes.
What does that mean?
Our incredible Creator **knew** that it would take the act of our **savior**, Jesus, to redeem our lost humanity.
So, **knowing** this, He spoke of it as "being done" before He created us!  Why?  Because he knew we would fall from righteousness and would need "redemption", ie., the forgiveness only He could provide.
He gave us **life**, we failed, He gave us forgiveness, at the highest price possible: He sacrificed **himself** to rescue us from our failure to be all that He intended us to be.
So our Lord Jesus, **knew** when He became man, that He would ultimately need to absolutely necessarily give Himself to pay the price of our forgiveness.

And **this he did**!

Glory beyond **glory** for His Creation of us, created in His Image, giving us free will, and absorbing, **in Himself**, the Grace and Forgiveness His Holiness required!

Comment: Welcome to BH and thanks for joining in. Do read the tour to see how this site works. I think you have put true and wonderful things but the question references two verses which are about sons as burnt offerings. If one does not mention "sons" and "burnt offering" then one is not focusing on what is being asked. You could delete and have another go.